# Как перенести с одной страницы на другую, введенные данные input

Tags: javascript

Есть простая форма авторизации, а так же есть ссылка на регистрацию, форма на вид такая что человек сначала пишет email и пароль и потом нажимает не вход, а кнопку регистрацию, которая ведет на другую страницу. Как вот введенные данные email и пароля перенести на страницу регистрации при клике на a class="order_reg" ?

```
<form name="context_auth_form" action="/personal/order/order.php" method="post" valign="top" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) this.submit ()">
        <input type="hidden" name="AUTH_FORM" value="Y">
        <input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="AUTH">
        <input type="hidden" name="backurl" value="">
        
        
        <table>
            <tbody><tr class="field-row field-login"><td class="col-1"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Email:</font></font></td><td class="col-2">
                <input type="text" name="USER_LOGIN" maxlength="50" value="" size="17">
            </td></tr>
            <tr class="field-row field-password"><td class="col-1"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Password:</font></font></td><td class="col-2">
                <input type="password" name="USER_PASSWORD" maxlength="50" size="17">
            </td></tr>
            
            
                    </tbody></table>

        <div class="reg_btns_wrapper">
            <input type="hidden" name="Login" value="Войти на сайт">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><input type="submit" value="Sign in"></font></font>
            <a class="order_reg" href="/personal/auth/registration.php"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Registration</font></font></a>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

на странице авторизации добавил так

```
<script>
 $('.order_reg').on('click', function(){
let reg_ema = document.querySelector("input[name='USER_LOGIN']").value;
let reg_pass = document.querySelector("input[name='USER_PASSWORD']").value;
sessionStorage.setItem('email_val', reg_ema);
sessionStorage.setItem('pass_val', reg_pass);
 });
</script>
```

на странице регистрации

```
        <script>
      var email_val = sessionStorage.getItem('email_val');
    var rega_pass = sessionStorage.getItem('pass_val');
    document.querySelector("input[name='REGISTER[EMAIL]']").value = email_val;
    document.querySelector("input[name='REGISTER[PASSWORD]']").value = rega_pass; 
</script>
```